# Passing a Date variable to a sql query with python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I´m trying to write a sql query in python, where I want the user to pass a date, saved in a variable. Then I want this to be processed in the query. While it´s pretty easy to do so in R, I´m curious if there´s an easy approach in python too.
The Date should be passed where 2022-12-12 is.

```py
date = input("this format  YYYY-MM-DD") 
query_new_Limits = """
SELECT #######
  , a.RULE_NAME
  , a.RESULT_VALUE
  , a.SUMMARY_DETAIL
  , a.REF_DATE
FROM ######## a ################### b
ON b.T_PORTFOLIO_ID = a.PORTFOLIO_ID
WHERE a.REF_DATE = TO_DATE('2022-12-12','YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(a.PORTFOLIO_CODE,'^[[:digit:]]+$')
  AND NOT b.POR_INVESTMENT_TYPE IN #######
  AND b.REF_TO_DATE > TO_DATE('2022-12-12','YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND a.RESULT_STATE_ID > 12
"""
```

Comment: What exactly is the question, do you only want the user to be able to input the date in that format or is the issue converting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick advice:

- avoid "date" as variable name as it's a reserved word
- maybe the underlying driver is not using parameters "bind by name" - try passing an array of parameters as ( '2022-12-31', '2022-12-31') or such, just to rule out the parameter name issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html)

> SQL and PL/SQL statements that pass data to and from Oracle Database should use placeholders in SQL and PL/SQL statements that mark where data is supplied or returned. These placeholders are referred to as bind variables or bind parameters. A bind variable is a colon-prefixed identifier or numeral. For example, there are two bind variables (dept_id and dept_name) in this SQL statement:
>
> ```py
> sql = """insert into departments (department_id, department_name)
>         values (:dept_id, :dept_name)"""
> cursor.execute(sql, [280, "Facility"])
> ```
>
> [or named binding]
>
> ```py
> cursor.execute("""
>         insert into departments (department_id, department_name)
>         values (:dept_id, :dept_name)""", dept_id=280,
>         dept_name="Facility")
> ```

Which applied to your example gives:

```py
date = input("this format  YYYY-MM-DD") 
query_new_Limits = """
SELECT #######
  , a.RULE_NAME
  , a.RESULT_VALUE
  , a.SUMMARY_DETAIL
  , a.REF_DATE
FROM ######## a ################### b
ON b.T_PORTFOLIO_ID = a.PORTFOLIO_ID
WHERE a.REF_DATE = TO_DATE(:date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(a.PORTFOLIO_CODE,'^[[:digit:]]+$')
  AND NOT b.POR_INVESTMENT_TYPE IN #######
  AND b.REF_TO_DATE > TO_DATE(:date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND a.RESULT_STATE_ID > 12
"""
cursor.execute(query_new_Limits, date=date)  # using kwarg binding
```

Comment: Thank you mate, is there a way to pass this to a pd.read_sql ? because there is no kwarg date ?

Comment: Underneath `pd.read_sql` is [`pd.read_sql_query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas-read-sql-query), which has a `params` kwarg into which you can pass a dict `{"date": date}`.

Comment: sorry for bothering but I get an error, that the bind variablename is not valid

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I can't help more I'm afraid.

Comment: I edited the sql query the way you posted it .                                                     
 new_limits = pd.read_sql_query(query_new_Limits,connection_db("####","###"),params={"date": date})